# Audio continues after fancyBox closes

Tags: fancybox-2

I've got a jwplayer inside fancyBox. The audio plays to the end of the clip even if I close the FB window. I thought I needed to use a callback but I am not sure how to set it up. I'm hoping someone can let me know what is missing from my code to correct this problem.

Thanks.

```
<p class="fancylist"><a id="inline" href="#samples">Listen to Samples</a></p>
<div style="display:none;">

<div id="samples" style="width:550px;">
<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'flashplayer': 'http://www.mydomain.com/player.swf',
'playlistfile': 'http://www.mydomain.com/Playlist.php',
'playlistsize': '500',
'playlist': 'bottom',
'controlbar': 'bottom',
'width': '470',
'height': '400'
});

</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is closing the fancy box just (more than likely) sets the `display:none;` on the div used for the fancy box. This means that the div is still on the page  and your video is still playing, you just can't see it.

Check out this link. Very similar question.

[Website youtube embedded video keeps playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615031/website-youtube-embedded-video-keeps-playing)

Comment: Mike is correct. You'll need to remove the actual object from the DOM in order for the audio to stop. Or even call the actual stop function on the appropriate library.

Comment: @michael try putting the contents of the hidden div in a separated html file, then call that file using `type: "iframe"` within your custom fancybox script. I think is a bad idea to use inline videos or audio ... they also create an overhead on page load.

Comment: Thanks to all of you forgetting back to me so quickly. @JFK, I wasn't aware of the overhead issue. I'll use the iframe.